# Puppeteer - UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning

Tags: node.js, pdf, npm, puppeteer

I tried using the puppeteer,

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('https://10.1.40.117/print/d37a2017-4bc4-46fb-9a8a-7ddc31e65a33', {waitUntil: 'networkidle2'});
  await page.pdf({path: 'hn.pdf', format: 'A4'});

  await browser.close();
})();
```

Getting the below error,

```
(node:16064) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID at https://10.1.40.117/print/d37a2017-4bc4-46fb-9a8a-7ddc31e65a33
(node:16064) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Any help on this?

Comment: Basically, I am trying to generate a PDF file from the https secure web page

Comment: The error already says what the problem is. There are problems with secure connection. Did you try to open it in browser?

Comment: Yes... It is getting opened in the browser...

Comment: See https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/1137#issuecomment-345861131

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `ignoreHTTPSErrors: true` when launching the browser instance. This happens when you use a self signed certificate locally.

Solution:

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ignoreHTTPSErrors: true});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code from my production setup

- List item
- Enable stealth mode (via puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth)
- Randomize User-agent or Set a valid one (via user-agents)
- Randomize Viewport size
- Skip images/styles/fonts loading for better performance
- Pass "WebDriver check"
- Pass "Chrome check"
- Pass "Notifications check"
- Pass "Plugins check"
- Pass "Languages check"

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer-extra')
const UserAgent = require('user-agents');
const StealthPlugin = require('puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth')

const USER_AGENT = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.75 Safari/537.36';
puppeteer.use(StealthPlugin())

function ResourceManager(loadImages) {
    let browser = null;
    const _this = this;
    let retries = 0;
    let isReleased = false;

    this.init = async () => {
        isReleased = false;
        retries = 0;
        browser = await runBrowser();
    };

    this.release = async () => {
        isReleased = true;
        if (browser) await browser.close();
    }

    this.createPage = async (url) => {
        if (!browser) browser = await runBrowser();
        return await createPage(browser,url);
    }

    async function runBrowser () {
        const bw = await puppeteer.launch({
            headless: true,
            devtools: false,
            ignoreHTTPSErrors: true,
            slowMo: 0,
            args: ['--disable-gpu','--no-sandbox','--no-zygote','--disable-setuid-sandbox','--disable-accelerated-2d-canvas','--disable-dev-shm-usage', "--proxy-server='direct://'", "--proxy-bypass-list=*"]
        });

        bw.on('disconnected', async () => {
            if (isReleased) return;
            console.log("BROWSER CRASH");
            if (retries <= 3) {
                retries += 1;
                if (browser && browser.process() != null) browser.process().kill('SIGINT');
                await _this.init();
            } else {
                throw "===================== BROWSER crashed more than 3 times";
            }
        });

        return bw;
    }
    // userDataDir: '/tmp',

    async function createPage (browser,url) {
        const userAgent = new UserAgent();
        const UA = userAgent.toString() || USER_AGENT;
        const page = await browser.newPage();
        await page.setViewport({
            width: 1920 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 100),
            height: 3000 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 100),
            deviceScaleFactor: 1,
            hasTouch: false,
            isLandscape: false,
            isMobile: false,
        });
        await page.setUserAgent(UA);
        await page.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        await page.setDefaultNavigationTimeout(0);
        if (!loadImages) {
            await page.setRequestInterception(true);
            //TODO: test
            page.on('request', (req) => {
                if(req.resourceType() == 'stylesheet' || req.resourceType() == 'font' || req.resourceType() == 'image'){
                    req.abort();
                } else {
                    req.continue();
                }
            });
        }

        await page.evaluateOnNewDocument(() => {
            Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'webdriver', {
                get: () => false,
            });
        });

        await page.evaluateOnNewDocument(() => {
            // We can mock this in as much depth as we need for the test.
            window.chrome = {
                runtime: {},
                // etc.
            };
        });

        await page.evaluateOnNewDocument(() => {
            const originalQuery = window.navigator.permissions.query;
            return window.navigator.permissions.query = (parameters) => (
                parameters.name === 'notifications' ?
                    Promise.resolve({ state: Notification.permission }) :
                    originalQuery(parameters)
            );
        });

        await page.evaluateOnNewDocument(() => {
            // Overwrite the `plugins` property to use a custom getter.
            Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'plugins', {
                // This just needs to have `length > 0` for the current test,
                // but we could mock the plugins too if necessary.
                get: () => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
            });
        });

        await page.evaluateOnNewDocument(() => {
            // Overwrite the `plugins` property to use a custom getter.
            Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'languages', {
                get: () => ['en-US', 'en'],
            });
        });

        await page.goto(url, { waitUntil: 'networkidle2',timeout: 0 } );
        return page;
    }
}

module.exports = {ResourceManager}
```